# New Google page speed insight

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Can anyone help me to get optimized images, scripts and css files using google page-speed insight. My site had optimized images and other optimized stuff but because of changes in page speed insight tool its all lost. Please help to sort out this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to optimise website is to add it to cloudflare. In speed tab there is options Auto Minify and Rocket loader. They do a job.
My website https://seos.lv/ has google pagespeed insights score on desktop 100 and mobile 96.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have any reference or tutorial link which will be helpful for guiding me about this.

Comment: It should be easy. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201720164-Step-2-Create-a-Cloudflare-account-and-add-a-website there is plenty of tutorials in internet and cloudflare docs.